# getting data from the tradingview volume indicator

Tags: python-3.x, algorithmic-trading, binance, tradingview-api, binance-api-client

there is a candle volume indicator on binance in tradingview.
[image]

How do I get the value of this indicatorfrom binance API.
the values I get from there are not similar to the values of this indicator
From binance APi i get data 127.07945000

Please, help

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of volume.

Volume in Asset quantity (12 BTC , 20 BTC)

Volume in USD quantity (5.4M USDT, 10M USDT)

If you are using binance api then it is returning volume in asset form.